# Why do we have to specify the input and output patch size of tessellation shaders separately?

Tags: opengl, rendering, tessellation

The Khronos [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader) for the *Tessellation Control Shader* states that

> The output patch size does not have to match the input patch size.

Why is that? And why do we have to specify the input patch size at all when the control shader is able to change that before the primitive generation gets the patch?

### Update

Is the following explanation correct?

The *input patch* (to the TCS) size is set by `glPatchParameter(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, X)`. This has the consequence that the length of the `in` attribute arrays is X.

```
TCS:
in vec4 vs_tc_position[]; // This has a length of X
```

The *output patch* size is defined by the TCSs `layout (vertices = Y) out;`. This means the length of the *out* attribute arrays is Y.

```
TCS:
out vec4 tc_te_position[]; // This has a length of Y
```

The TCS is **called Y times** and passes the output directly to the TES. So, the `in` attribute arrays of the TES have a length of Y.

```
TES:
in vec4 tc_te_position[]; // This has a length of Y
```

The number of output patch vertices is irrelevant to the Tessellation Primitive Generation (TPG) because it only sees an *abstract patch*. The number of vertices of the abstract patch is defined by the TESs `layout (TYPE) in;`.

The TES is called for every new vertex that results from the *abstract patch* due to the tessellation levels defined by the TCS (when it exists) or by `glPatchParameter(GL_PATCH_DEFAULT_{OUTER|INNER}_LEVEL)`. The TES can then interpolate the attributes based on the `gl_TessCoord` from the abstract patch and all the vertices (which are more like control points) from the TCS.

#### Example

So, the following situation could be possible.

```
glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 1);
```

The TCS gets one vertex per patch.

```
layout (vertices = 5) out;
```

The TCS creates 5 vertices for the output patch. Somehow.

```
layout (quads) in;
```

The TPG uses a quad as an abstract patch and subdivides. Then the TES is called on every new vertex and interpolates the attribute of the 5 output vertices from the TCS with the `gl_TessCoord` from the *abstract patch* (somehow) to compute the attributes for the new vertices.

Answer (score 3):

The input patch size has to be specified because you don't *have* to have a TCS at all.

Also, remember that the input patch size is used to interpret the stream of vertices you render with. Every X vertices is a single patch, so OpenGL needs to know what X to use. Even with a TCS, OpenGL needs to have an input size to know how many vertices to pass to the TCS operation.

As for why the input and output patch sizes can be different, that is there to give freedom to the TCS and the user to do whatever they want. TCS's are able to add, remove, or modify data however they want, including adding or removing entire values.

So a TCS can turn a single input vertex into 4 output vertices; this could be useful for something like quad tessellation.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the TCS being optional. Please check the **Update** to my question to clarify this further.

Comment: @NicolBolas Quick follow-up question — can the input patch size be specified using primitive restart functionality? According to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElements.xhtml, `glMultiDrawElements` supports `GL_PATCHES`, which makes me think that primitive restart should then also work...

Comment: @Ailurus: Multi-draw functionality has nothing to do with primitive restart stuff. And nor does primitive restarting care what the patch type is; it will function. But it will also be *useless*. Primitive restart is useful for triangle strips/fans and line strips/loops. Patches are *always* individual, like triangle lists/line lists/points. So if you want to "restart" a patch primitive... you just add X more indices to the list, where X is the patch size.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know, but in some sense they are comparable (see e.g. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart). From the `glMultiDrawElements` specs (see previous comment) it seems that in one call patches of different input size can be rendered — if that is true, then I'd think that this should also be possible using primitive restart. I actually have a scenario where I have patches of different input size (their output sizes are all the same). Perhaps I should open a new question on this? Thanks.

Comment: @Ailurus: "*if that is true, then I'd think that this should also be possible using primitive restart.*" The fact that they have some overlap in behavior doesn't change what I said: the two features have nothing to do with each other. "*I actually have a scenario where I have patches of different input size (their output sizes are all the same).*" That's a different question. And the answer is "no, you can't." Primitive restart cannot affect shader quantities. And this includes static properties like patch size.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, I see. Then to conclude — can `glMultiDrawElements` indeed render patches of different input size (in one call)? If so, then the individual counts (of indices) in that command would take priority over glPatchParameter(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, X)? If not, what's the use of supporting `GL_PATCHES` in `glMultiDrawElements`?

Comment: @Ailurus: Have you looked at `glMultiDrawElements`'s signature? Do you see a parameter for "patch primitive size"? No. There's a parameter for index count, but that works exactly like the one in `glDrawElements`. And `glMultiDrawElements` supports patch primitives because there's no reason for it *not* to do so.